# Does a program running in terminal stop when Ubuntu automatically suspends?

Tags: suspend, 20.04, automatic

If one of my programs is running in the background, and "automatic suspend on battery power" is ON, will the program stop running after the specified time when computer is suspended?

Comment: Hey :) Can you make your title a little more precise? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, all programs will stop running.